# Use of Timer and Url downloading web source not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a timer set up and it downloads the source of a text file for a phone number. No matter what I change the text in the text file on the server to it always stays the same phone number. How can I get it to download the latest string?

```
  func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function **Countdown** with the interval of 1 seconds
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1/5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func updateCounting()
{

    view.window?.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel()) + 1
    if (currentNumber == "")
    {
        resizeSmall()
    }
    else{
        resizeLarge()
    }
  //  let urls = URL(string : "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.net/CallerID/" + accountID + "/phone.txt")
    guard var urls = URL(string : "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.net/CallerID/" + accountID + "/phone.txt")
        else {
            print("Error:  doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            return
    }
    do{
        var phonenumber = try String(contentsOf: urls, encoding: .ascii)
        if (phonenumber != "" && !NumberList.contains(phonenumber))
        {
            NumberList.append(phonenumber)
             print(phonenumber)
            TableView.reloadData()
    urls.removeAllCachedResourceValues()

        }

    }catch{

    }

}
```

It always returns the same phone number even though I constantly change it

Comment: Sorry I accidentally hit save before uploading code

Comment: Code is up now Idk what is up.  I tried clearing the cache of the url.

Comment: Loading data from a remote URL synchronously 5 times a second is most likely not working. Are you seriously considering that kind of polling?

Comment: The thing is that I have a windows application that does the exact same thing as this using an WebClient and it works just expected.

Comment: And I do a similar rate. The text file has a php file populating it when a phone call comes in and it populates the file with a phone number which is then downloaded using my application. I have had no errors with it on the windows side